# Elastic Search: Not able to connect to cluster with Java NodeBuilder Client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to connect a client to ElasticSearch cluster and I am not able to get it working. I referred other questions here and in elastic search forum but none of the suggestions there helped me.

I am able to telnet to each of elastic search nodes over port `9300`.

Cluster status is green and I am able to connect using `TransportClient` without any issues.

Code (Scala) :

```
  val immutableSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder
    .put("node.name", "node-client")
    .put("http.enabled", "false")
    .put("index.number_of_shards", 5)
    .put("index.number_of_replicas", 3)
    .put("cluster.name", "my-cluster")
    .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
    .putArray("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "host1:9300", "host2:9300","host3:9300", "host4:9300", "host5:9300")
    .build

  lazy val node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
    .loadConfigSettings(false)
    .client(true)
    .settings(immutableSettings)
    .node()
```

Exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master]
```

I understand this is because the client is not able to join the cluster but I am not able to figure out why.

I checked logs in all of the 5 nodes and I don't see anything getting logged. And I also don't have enough permissions to change the logging level.

Comment: Did you check the state of your cluster? with a command curl per example?

Comment: @eliasah Cluster status is green and I am able to connect using `TransportClient` without any issues.

Comment: Do you have enough resources to be able to create a new Node and make it join the cluster? Here it says that there is no master available. You might also what to check elasticsearch logs for more details and updated your post.

Comment: @eliasah I checked logs for all the 5 nodes and I don't see anything getting logged. And I also don't have enough permissions to change the logging level.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions also to create the node

Comment: Why did you disable the http?

Comment: @eliasah What permissions do I need to be able to create a node? Permission regarding logging level is that I don't have write permissions to change `logging.yml`. I was trying different things and neither enabling or disabling http made any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64156/discussion-between-eliasah-and-prasanna).